# Data authorization and OAuth

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to know if there is a way within OAuth to limit the data a user can see once the token has been accessed.  For example, in the 'photo sharing' sample where one application contains a list of photos and another application wants access to the photos for printing purposes.  How can the user indicate the photo print service should see a subset of the photos?  Maybe I only want the printing service to see photos with a .jpg extension, or photos with after a certain date, or with a certain 'tag'.  Where can additional authorization requirements be populated?
I have a java application and we are using Spring Security OAuth2 and hopefully we can accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can use 'scope' for that purpose. Define a custom 'scope', and the endpoint of your service should interpret the custom scope and behave based on that.

For example, define 'pic_jpeg' as a scope name and describe about the scope in your API document like "'pic_jpeg' scope is required to access JPEG pictures."

A client application will access your authorization endpoint with a parameter 'scope=pic_jpeg scopeX scopeY', and your OAuth 2.0 authorization server implementation will finally issue an access token which is associated with the scopes (pic_jpeg scopeX and scopeY). The client application then accesses the 'pictures' endpoint of your service with the access token, so the endpoint should confirm that the access token is associated with 'pic_jpeg' scope and allow the client application to access JPEG pictures only when confirmed.